# Почему JS не возвращает значение? undefined

Tags: javascript

Есть 2 скрипта для обновления двух списков. Второй скрипт работает, но данные не передает в контроллер. Первый неправильно возвращает значения и выдает :"undefined"
Первый скрипт:
'''

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#carbrands").change(function () {
                    console.log("pehla andar");
                    $("#carmodels").empty();
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '@Url.Action("GetModels")',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: { id: $("#carbrands").val() },
                        success: function (mems) {
                            console.log("wich ayaeee");
                            $.each(mems, function (i, member) {
                                $("#carmodels").append('<option value="'
        + member.Value + '">'
                                    + member.Text + '</option>');
                            });
                        },
                        error: function (ex) {
                            alert('Failed to retrieve states.' + ex);
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                })
            });
        </script>
        }
```

'''
Второй скрипт:
'''

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#carbrands').change(function()
        {
            var id = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '@Url.Action("GetItems")/' + id,
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#carmodels').replaceWith(data);
                }
            });
        });
    })
        </script>
```

'''

Кто разбирается в JS, знаете в чем дело?

Comment: Задайте два отдельных вопроса.

Answer (score -1):

`Each` создает функцию, старайся всегда перебирать через `for(){}`

`var`, `function` и `callbacks` морально и нет - устарели
(По колбекам есчо: если у тебя в коде полно строк с +5 табами, значит пора пылесосить песок)

Обычно в js используют одинарные кавычки для строк

Пробуй сначала выводить в консоль, потом уже вставлять текст в дом

Вот [вкусная статья](https://habr.com/ru/post/305900/) к прочтению

Рекомендую также использовать [расширение](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/js-exec/caeimpdeapdimekjkkkggpibnlijlnka) для быстрых тестов своего кода (корпсы главное солблюдай)

Вот код асинхронного запроса:

```js
const afetch=(_url)=>{
    return new Promise((resolve)=>{
        $.ajax({
            url: _url,
            type: 'GET',
            data: {},
            async: true,
        }).done((r)=>{
            if(!r)r = false;
            resolve(r);
        }).catch((e)=>{
            console.log(e.status, e.responseText, e);
            resolve(false);
        });
    });
};

(async()=>{
    let r = await afetch('http://www.calorizator.ru/analyzer/recipe/');

    // code, any job with response

    console.log('response', r);
})();
```

*Я знаю про await ajax, но работает он раз через раз, у меня*

Comment: Each не создаёт никакие функции, он их запускает, уже созданные, и то не факт (компилятор может распознать цикл и скомпилировать сразу вместо вызова функций). И кроме for есть ещё куча способов перебора. А var, function и колбэки не устарели - они используются по прямому назначению там, где необходимо. Да даже в вашем ответе.